# vuex commits empty array instead not empty array

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

Problem: When trying to commit array value inside async function vuex module state get **empty array**

'name' is Vuex module name

```js
const data = await RM.getEntity(name, id, query)
store.commit(name + '/set', { id, data })
```

there is Vuex module mutation part:

```js
set: (state, payload) => {
  if (Array.isArray(payload.data))
    console.log('commit', JSON.stringify(state.data), payload.id, payload.data);
  Vue.set(state.data, payload.id, payload.data)
},
```

there is 3 iteration callback by 3 components

log output:

[image]

array data not manipulated after (code below not make it better):

```js
if (Array.isArray(payload.data)) {
  console.log('commit array', JSON.stringify(state.data), payload.id, JSON.stringify(payload.data));
  Vue.set(state.data, payload.id, [...payload.data])
} else {
  console.log('commit object', JSON.stringify(state.data), payload.id, JSON.stringify(payload.data));
  Vue.set(state.data, payload.id, { ...payload.data })
}
```

[image: new logs]

Comment: this code work perfect with objects in payload.data

Comment: I can't reproduce this ~ https://jsfiddle.net/jyqow90d/. There must be something else manipulating your store that you're not showing

Comment: looks like something wrong with 3 components lifecycly beforemount trigger

Comment: I really don't know what that means, sorry 

Comment: You sure the data is not empty the moment you assign it, but get filled later? Some bad async code somewhere?